# Installing IPOPT for Matlab R2015a on Mac OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, matlab, mex, ipopt

I'm attempting to install the Matlab interface for IPOPT. I'm following the directions on https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki/MatlabInterface.

I've successfully configured Matlab to build MEX files. Running

```
 mex -setup
```

from Matlab is supposed to generate a file mexopts.sh (which should be located in ./matlab/ directory). However, I don't seem to have this directory any where on my computer.

Furthermore, it seems that, starting in version R2014a, Matlab no longer uses .sh files (see: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/124597-how-to-setup-gfortran-on-mac-osx-10-9-and-matlab-r2014a#comment_211324).

Does anyone have any idea on how to install the Matlab interface for IPOPT for R2015a on El Capitan? Sifting through the pages of old directions online has not helped much.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "where is the mexopts.sh in Matlab2015a on Mac OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)".

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the file can be found at:

```
'matlabroot'/bin
```